# NDepend: Multiple TFS Branches lead to "several assemblies have the name but are different"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, ndepend

I'm new to NDepend at work and am trying to get my head wrapped around some of the basics. I tried searching online but couldn't come across the answer for this one.

### The Background

We're using TFS 2010 (I know, I know; we're looking to update that whole process.) within TFS, we're using branches. And since TFS doesn't have a concept of a "working directory" (to my knowledge), I usually wind up on my desktop with something along the lines of:

```
\MyProjects
    \ProjectName-Branch1
        \ProjectName.sln
    \ProjectName-Branch2
        \ProjectName.sln
```

As these are branches, I expect them to contain different code.

### The Problem

The problem arises when I try to analyze an assembly. I do the following:

- Open one of the branch solutions (e.g. `ProjectName-Branch1\ProjectName.sln`)
- I check my solution file out for editing.
- I head to `NDepend` --> `Attach NDepend Project to Current VS Solution`

However, despite attaching it only to that project, I see a number of errors along the lines of:

> Several .NET assemblies have the name {ProjectAssemblyName} but they are different.

It then lists DLL files from both branch folders.

### My Question

How do I avoid this conflict to help NCover exclude branch folders from each other, and ensure it doesn't occur again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the NDepend support response, which I'm posting here for reference:

> NDepend project takes a list of assembly name (without file extension) and a list of directories. It then resolves assemblies in these directory by name, and if several assemblies with the same name are found, you get the error.
>
> What you can do is go to : NDepend > Project Properties > Code to Analyze > Folders
> and erase the folders of the branch(es) you want to discard.

This did seem to resolve the issue for me.